# How to force Google cloud endpoints to use https only on whole API or specific methods?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to be sure that endpoints API serves information only via **https**:

1. How to force API to use **https** only on **whole API**.
2. How to force **specific method** to use **https** only.

What kind of code I should include in Google App Engine Java or Python27?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints *only* serves deployed APIs over **https**, by default, and without a way to override it. If this is your desired behavior, you're all set.

During local testing you will see APIs served over **http**, but this is due to the lack of certificates and support for SSL in the local server.

Comment: 80% of answer to score - one completion please if you know? Can I serve endpoints without certificate mean `https://app-id.appspot.com` on production or I have to buy some certificate to start infrastructure https://my-domain.com (no want to do it but if required I need think about it)?

Comment: Yes, you can serve on https://app-id.appspot.com without paying for a certificate. (There is a certificate, but it's Google's and you don't have to pay for it.)

Comment: @DanHolevoet Sorry to revive a 2-year old thread. I have a follow-up question on similar lines. Can my non-SSL custom domain say http://www.my-domain.com access my endpoints at https://app-id.appspot.com ?